# .NET 3.5 Equivalent for ReadAllLines and WriteAllLines in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I am trying to create an application that can open a .csv file, add some user inputted text to the end of particular lines, then save and close that file. I've seen many many solutions that use ReadAllLines and WriteAllLines to achieve this but for certain reasons I am stuck using VS2008 and .NET 3.5 which apparently don't have those. I was wondering if anyone knows of an equivalent method to achieve these in 3.5. If I could create an array holding each line of text in the file, I could perhaps be able to access particular lines using their index in the array, add the text I want to them, then save the file. Sadly, I am not sure how to do this or if it is even possible. I'm still fairly new to C# so this might be complete gibberish but I hope it isn't! If anyone has any suggestions for how I could possibly go about this, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` are your friends, like in the good ol' time.

Comment: See how to make your own here http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,8d10107b7a92c5c2

Comment: @DaveShaw ... and that's when I realize that the implementations are not lazy... o.o - I'm not sure where I got the assumption they were

Comment: File.Read/WriteAllLines() have been available since .NET 2.0

Comment: @HansPassant - what is new are the WriteAllLines overloads that take IEnumerable<string> (instead of just string[]). That's probably the "laziness" being referred to (though note that ReadAllLines still returns string[]).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (alter to your specific needs). Yeah, maybe not as elegant as some solutions, but it should be wicked fast:

```
public void AddUserBS(string filePath, string separator, string userBS)
{
  var reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
  var writer = new StreamReader(filePath + "tmp");

  string line;

  while(null != (line = reader.ReadLine())
  {
     writer.Write(line + separator + userBS);
  }

  reader.Dispose();
  writer.Dispose();

  File.Delete(filePath);
  File.Rename(filePath + "tmp", filePath)
}
```